# Data not received while uploading csv file to database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, csv

I have developed a page to upload a big CSV(greater than 7000 rows) file to the database. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes not. Sometimes, I am getting an error like "Data not received" in the middle of uploading. But the values are inserted into the database upto that moment. I have checked the php.ini in the server:

```
max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60     ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
```

Server has a lot of projects, all of them are using zend framework. But I am using simple PHP for my project. My system admin said, php.ini file is / here, usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini

Any suggestions?

Comment: Set `max_execution = 9999; Also, you can get chunks from the CSV instead of getting a line at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will change the execution time. "you can get chunks from the CSV instead of getting a line at a time. " I didn't get that. How can I do it?

Comment: `max_execution_time = 9999;` As for the chunking, you'd have to pull it all in as an array first and then chunk the array.

Comment: I don't need all columns from the csv file. So can I use the chunk method for that as well?